# Can one can help with my capsicum plants?

Tags: capsicum-pubsecens

[image]

Hello everyone,

I am new to gardening, I have problems with my capsicum plants, I have about 10 plants, they all have curved leaves, and huge leaves. They don’t look healthy. I spread neem oil mix on them over last two weeks, there is no difference. So can anybody help?

Cheers
Bianca
[image]

Comment: I need more information with watering frequency, compost used and when it was potted. Also, is there any insects on the plants such as aphids?

Comment: No idea what neem oil is, but I agree: I would suspect insects (aphids, scale, etc) and/or watering.  They look like they were very healthy not that long ago!  I find aphids love new leaf buds, so that would be a good place to start a search.

Comment: @winwaed Neem oil is a pretty effective contact pesticide against aphids and similar soft-bodied insects.